# Spark : subtractByKey issue (pyspark)

Tags: pyspark

I have some kinds of issues with subtractByKey.

I have 2 files :
**First one is like :**  (Client ID + Client Mail)

```
client_id   emails

4A85FD8E-197D-2AE3-B939-A527AFF16A04    imperdiet.non.vestibulum@mon***tur.com 
D48D530C-CF68-DAF1-18F0-E0A0A03F3E06    rutrum.urna@estm***ncus.net:facilisis@i****m.ca
40815230-25DC-9EA0-01D1-2706B4B56958    iaculis.nec.eleifend@gr****nc.net 
...
```

**and the second one :** (Only Mail)

```
pharetra@P****s.com  
ut.aliquam@o****m.org  
erat@a****e.edu 
....
```

Some lines in the first file can have 2 (or more) mails with this format :

```
mail:mail
```

What did i do :

```
*test1=sc.textFile("file1")
*test2=sc.textFile("file2")
*test3=test1.subtractByKey(test2)
```

**and the result is ... :**

```
[(u'A', u'B'), (u'A', u'D'), (u'A', u'1'), (u'A', u'D'), (u'A', u'D'), (u'A', u'B'), (u'A', u'F'), (u'A', u'E'), (u'A', u'9'), (u'A', u'5'), (u'A', u'9'), (u'A', u'6'), (u'c', u'l'), (u'E', u'8'), (u'E', u'4'), (u'E', u'6'), (u'E', u'6'), (u'E', u'7'), (u'E', u'5'), (u'E', u'5'), (u'E', u'5'), (u'E', u'2'), (u'E', u'8'), (u'C', u'2'), (u'C', u'5'), (u'C', u'6'), (u'C', u'C'), (u'C', u'E'), (u'C', u'3'), (u'C', u'F'), (u'C', u'4'), (u'C', u'B'), (u'C', u'F'), (u'C', u'F'), (u'C', u'8'), (u'C', u'0'), (u'1', u'D'), (u'1', u'2'), (u'1', u'3'), (u'1', u'8'), (u'1', u'0'), (u'1', u'F'), ... ]
```

I wanted to delete clients in the first file who had their mails in the second file but it did not work.

Comment: you'd better edit your question in `code` format, cause what I see is quite confusing

Comment: there is no code in it ... except 3 lines, which are in code format.

Comment: it is the first file that could contains multi emails, right?

Comment: yes sry. Editing !

Answer (score 0):

> note: I am not very familiar with `pyspark` but the spark api should be the
>   same.

first you should make email as the key

`rdd1=sc.textFile("file1").map(lambda line: (line.split(" ")[0], line.split(" ")[1]))`

this will give you a rdd of

```
[(4A85FD8E-197D-2AE3-B939-A527AFF16A04,imperdiet.non.vestibulum@mon***tur.com)]
```

then as there may be multi email, you should do a `flatMapValues()`

`rdd2 = rdd1.flatMapValues(lambda email: email.split(":"))`

this will give you a pair rdd and each one just contains one email

now you can switch the key and value

```
rdd3=rdd2.map(lambda kv: (kv[1], kv[0]))
```

now you get a rdd that using user email as a key and the UUID as a value
such as

```
[(imperdiet.non.vestibulum@mon***tur.com, 4A85FD8E-197D-2AE3-B939-A527AFF16A04)]
```

now you should find which UUID's email is contained in file2, to do that you should load the second file as a rdd:

```
secondRdd = sc.textFile("file2").map(lambda line: (line, 1))
```

and do a `join` and tweak the join result rdd.

```
rdd4 = rdd3.join(secondRdd).map(lambda kv: (kv[1][0], kv[0]))
```

if everything is right now you should get a rdd which is as the format of `(UUID, email)` which represents all the users whose email occurs in `file2`,

then you can do a `subtractByKey()` with `rdd1` which we originally got.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. If i can add a question : It will erase the client if the email is in file2. Ok, but if the client has 2 mails, will it erase one of the occurences or both of them ? (I guessed ur flatmap dupplicate the client ? )

Comment: you should notice that, `rdd1` hasn't been flatMap yet, and yes, I think if there are duplicate 'UUID', `subtractByKey()` will [ease all](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html#tbl-pair-two-transformations)